# I have tried to share data between notification service extension and main app using app group in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, nsuserdefaults, swift4.2, ios-app-group

I have tried to share data between notification service extension and main app using app group in iOS, i have complete the set up and done every thing correctly , still i am not able receive data in my app my code is

in NotificationService exteension

let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.notificationServiceExtension.com")

```
    userDefaults?.addSuite(named: "group.notificationServiceExtension.com")

    userDefaults?.set(Data, forKey: "backgroundNotification1")

     userDefaults?.synchronize()
```

I am trying to access the data in app delegate my code in app delegate is

let userDefaults=UserDefaults()

userDefaults.addSuite(named: "group.notificationServiceExtension.com")

```
    let DataBackground = userDefaults.data(forKey: "backgroundNotification1")

   if DataBackground != nil{

    let  notification = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: DataBackground! as! Data)as!NSDictionary) as! [Int:[[String:Any]]]

     print(notification)
   }
```

While retrieving the data in my app i am getting

[User Defaults] Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x2829cc400> (Domain: group.notificationServiceExtension.com, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd
in my log

PS-I have already register same app group in my app and shared extension